# Using on('change') how can I bind an event listener to elements created after the <script>'s have run?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am using a cascading dropdown feature for my search page.

When the user selects a new element from the dropdown menu, a new dropdown menu should appear and so on.

I have another function to populate the dropdown menus so disregard the fact they have no elements.

```
$(".search-cascading-dropdown").on("change", function() {
    $("#search-cascading-dropdown-container").append("<select class='search-cascading-dropdown'></select>"); 
});
```

Once the new select box has been added, there isn't an event listener attached. How can I get this working so eachtime the user selects an entry from the dropdown list it creates a new list?

Comment: using delegation as change event bubbles

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use jQuery's [.on](http://api.jquery.com/on/) event delegation:

```
var $parent = $("#search-cascading-dropdown-container");
$parent.on("change", ".search-cascading-dropdown", function() {
  $parent.append("<select class='search-cascading-dropdown'></select>");
});
```

Comment: Why not attach the handler to `#search-cascading-dropdown-container`? - Oops - you just sort of said that :)

Answer (score 0):

Try something like this:

```
$(document).on("change",".search-cascading-dropdown",function() {
    $("#search-cascading-dropdown-container").append("<select class='search-cascading-dropdown'></select>"); 
});
```

Answer (score 0):

The on should be called on a parent of your .search-cascading-dropdown elements, and you should add the selector in the arguments of the "on" method :

```
$("#parent").on("change", ".search-cascading-dropdown", function(event){
   ...
});
```

That way, all change events occuring on descendants of #parent, filtered by the selector, will be handled by your event handler.

Source: http://api.jquery.com/on/#on-events-selector-data-handlereventObject

Hope that help.